# Gem conflict in Rails with Activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I keep getting this message when trying to spin the server in rails.

```
to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (= 6.0.0) - did find: [activesupport-5.2.2.1] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/louis/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/var/lib/gems/2.5.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all', execute `gem env` for more information
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gem, but I am wondering why my app is even expecting version 6.0.0, I am running rails 5.2.2.1 (and have to keep it that way) does anyone know what is happening and how I can resolve it.

Side note: I am using commands `gem such and such` rather than `bundle` for various reasons

Response to comments: The reason for not using bundle is because when I was using bundle to manage my dependencies for work, it was mismanaging the gems I had globally- so If I made a practice project and bundled, it would also change the gems for the project I work on professionally and cause conflicts- so now bundle has a different environment to my work project so I can create mini rails apps in my spare time. How do I remedy this situation?  Many Thanks

Comment: "Side note: I am using commands gem such and such rather than bundle for various reasons" - well thats your problem right there.

Comment: You don't normally install gems manually, when working on a project. The `Gemfile` (which you may edit yourself) defines all your direct dependencies, and the `Gemfile.lock` (which you should almost never edit yourself) specifies an exact version for every dependency, and dependency of a dependency, and every dependency of a dependency of a dependency, .... - so you get the full, well-defined list of absolutely everything needed to run the project.

Comment: To install everything in the `Gemfile.lock`, you must run: `bundle install`, or just `bundle` for short. In the event that you've managed to really mess things up (e.g. you've been editing gems directly on your local machine), you can run `bundle pristine` to force-reinstall everything.

Comment: TL;DR: Don't run `gem install xxx`. Just run `bundle install`.

Comment: The reason for not using bundle is because when I was using bundle to manage my dependencies for work, it was mismanaging the gems I had globally- so If I made a practice project and bundled, it would also change the gems for the project I work on professionally and cause conflicts- so now bundle has a different environment to my work project so I can create mini rails apps in my spare time. How do I remedy this situation?

Answer (score 0):

can you pass the gemfile and gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `bundle`.

This will install gems and resolve dependencies.